# Extract URLs out of email in Python

Tags: python, email, url

Thanks for your submission to ourdirectory.com
    URL: http://myurlok.us
    Please click below link to confirm your submission.
    http://www.ourdirectory.com/confirm.aspx?id=1247778154270076

```
Once we receive your comfirmation, your site will be included for process!
regards,

http://www.ourdirectory.com

Thank you!
```

Should be obvious which URL I need to extract.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you want to do this. What's it for?

Comment: surely an automated submission bot to some external site.

Comment: Yes, I have like thousands of these emails coming in that need to be confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works only if the source is not HTML.

```
def extractURL(self,fileName):

    wordsInLine = []
    tempWord = []
    urlList = []

    #open up the file containing the email
    file = open(fileName)
    for line in file:
        #create a list that contains each word in each line
        wordsInLine = line.split(' ')
        #For each word try to split it with :
        for word in wordsInLine:
            tempWord = word.split(":")
            #Check to see if the word is a URL
            if len(tempWord) == 2:
                if tempWord[0] == "http" or tempWord[0] == "https":
                    urlList.append(word)

    file.close()

    return urlList
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's HTML email with hyperlinks you could use the HTMLParse library as a shortcut.

```
import HTMLParser
class parseLinks(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for name, value in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    print value
                    print self.get_starttag_text()

someHtmlContainingLinks = ""
linkParser = parseLinks()
linkParser.feed(someHtmlContainingLinks)
```

Comment: his sample document doesn't look like HTML to me :-)

Comment: Everyone else provided non-HTML solutions, and the OP's question history indicates he's pulling it from gmail, which does support HTML.  Given the vagueness of the question, I think this is a valid response.

Answer (score 1):

@OP, if your email is always standard,

```
f=open("emailfile")
for line in f:
    if "confirm your submission" in line:
        print f.next().strip()        
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy. One suggestion (taken from the [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) library):

```
\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])
```

will match URLs (without `mailto:`, if you want that, say so), even if they are enclosed in parentheses. Will also match URLs without `http://` or `ftp://` etc. if they start with `www.` or `ftp.`.

A simpler version:

```
\bhttps?://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]
```

It all depends on what your needs are/what your input looks like.

Comment: I don't think you need to get so fancy. I think he wants to parse very specific emails from a very specific source, so I imagine he could parse for the exact string: "http://www.ourdirectory.com/confirm.aspx?id=" followed by digits and end-of-line.

Comment: Probably yes. Although there is another URL (myurlok.us) in there. Who knows what else might turn up - he wasn't very specific.

Answer (score 0):

regex:

```
"http://www.ourdirectory.com/confirm.aspx\?id=[0-9]+$"
```

or without regex, parse the email line by line and test if the string contains "http://www.ourdirectory.com/confirm.aspx?id=" and if it does, that's your URL.

Of course, if your input is actually the HTML source instead of the text you posted, this all goes out the window.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

I wrote a post for the same. The code in this post can extract URLs from an email file, whether it is plain-text or html content-types, or quoted-printable or base 64 or 7bit encodings.

[Python - How to extract URLs (plain/html, quote-printable/base64/7bit) from an email file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380726/python-how-to-extract-urls-plain-html-quote-printable-base64-7bit-from-an-e)